# SugarCRM - how to make users see only child users?

Tags: hierarchical-data, user-management, sugarcrm

I want to change the behaviour of Sugar CRM community version. Here's what sugar currently does:

1. Admin logs into Sugar
2. Admin clicks on Admin tab
3. Admin creates a new user named George with admin access
4. Under user information section, Admin makes George report to Admin (in the database, it will show users.report_to_id is the admin's user_id)
5. Admin saves and logs out
6. George logs in with his password
7. George goes to admin tab.
8. George goes to list users page and sees all users, including Admin, the person he is supposed to report to.

I want to change step 8 such that George is not allowed to see the user he "reports to". George should only be able to see child users and descendants of those child users.  George should not be able to see anyone above him.

How can I achieve this? will sugar support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that this requires a lot of code customization.  Here's a thread that explains it

http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=59216

Answer (score 0):

@John - You need to look at creating roles under role management.
Role management allows you to enable / disable rights.